# saving an array of objects within an object in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, persistent-storage

I am pretty new to swift and am trying to persist data. I created a class called Students where I store the basic properties of the student such as name and an array of schedule objects. The schedule is another class that contains a counter for each schedule instance.

```
class Students: NSObject, NSCoding{

var name: String = ""
var schedule = [Schedule]()

static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("students")

struct PropertyKey {
    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let scheduleKey = "schedule"
}



init(name: String, schedule: [Schedule]){
    self.name = name
    self.schedule = schedule

    super.init()
}

init(name: String)
{
    self.name = name

    super.init()
}


func addClass(className: String){
    let scheduleItem = Schedule()
    scheduleItem.scheduleName = className
    schedule.append(scheduleItem)
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name,forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(schedule, forKey: PropertyKey.scheduleKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String
    let schedule = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.scheduleKey) as! [Schedule]
    self.init(name: name, schedule: schedule)
}
```

}

```
class Schedule{

    var counter = 0
    var scheduleName: String = ""

    func increase()
    {
        counter += 1
    }

    func reset()
    {
        counter = 0
    }

}
```

My problem is that when I call my save method

```
func save(){
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(students, toFile: Students.ArchiveURL.path!)

    if !isSuccessfulSave {
        print("Failed to save meals...")
    }
}
```

I get an error from the line

```
aCoder.encodeObject(schedule, forKey: PropertyKey.scheduleKey)
```

Why will it not let me save the array of schedule objects?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Here is the error that I got. Behavior Tracker[28452:868887] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7ffe3ae00fa0 of class 'Behavior_Tracker.Schedule' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Behavior_Tracker.Schedule replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]